# How to set multiselect by default in highmaps?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In highmaps I can select multiple points by holding ctrl while clicking. How can I make it so multiple selection is the default behavior and there is no need to hold ctrl button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap `Highcharts.Point.prototype.select` method and permanently set `accumulate` argument to true:

```
(function(H) {
    H.wrap(H.Point.prototype, 'select', function(proceed, selected, accumulate) {
        accumulate = true;
        proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    });
}(Highcharts));
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/e2tj4onx/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts